# NodeJS mongodb query ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a nodejs mongoose backend api with express, whose objective is, for each website page, it returns a certain number of objects sorted by ID.

My question is relatively simple but it's easier to exemplify. Let's say the user has choosen to display 20 objects per page and it's on page 0. The api will return the first 20 objects (0 to 19) from the mongoDB collection. Page 2 with 20 will return the next 20 objects ordered by ID ( objects 20 to 39).

Right now the code looks like this:

```
 var page = (req.query.page) ? parseInt(req.query.page) : 0;
    var qtd = (req.query.qtt) ? parseInt(req.query.qtt) : 20;
    var min_value = page * qtd;
    var max_value =( page + 1 ) * qtd - 1;

    Order.find({}, {skip:min_value,limit:max_value}, function(err,orders) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                status: "error",
                message: err,
            });
        }
        res.json({
            status: "success",
            message: "Orders retrieved successfully",
            data: orders
        });
    });
};
```

My question is, why do I keep getting "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" and how would I sort the query alongside limit and skip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because whenever error gets occurred ,your `if (err)` gets  called which sends `response` to the client and then again after if condition  `res.json()` gets  called ,which throws error as `response` headers were already sent in the if condition above.
You can do something like this ,use else with if condition.

```
var page = (req.query.page) ? parseInt(req.query.page) : 0;
    var qtd = (req.query.qtt) ? parseInt(req.query.qtt) : 20;
    var min_value = page * qtd;
    var max_value =( page + 1 ) * qtd - 1;

    Order.find({}, {skip:min_value,limit:max_value}, function(err,orders) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                status: "error",
                message: err,
            });
        }
    else{
       res.json({
            status: "success",
            message: "Orders retrieved successfully",
            data: orders
        });

}

    });
};
```

Comment: Welp that fixed it, thanks, but now I have an error message that mongoDB seems to throw "Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion."

Comment: Thanks, but I got it working just now, it's because my min value was 0 when skip needs to start a 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var page = (req.query.page) ? parseInt(req.query.page) : 0;
    var qtd = (req.query.qtt) ? parseInt(req.query.qtt) : 20;
    var min_value = page * qtd;
    var max_value =( page + 1 ) * qtd - 1;

    Order.find({}, {skip:min_value,limit:max_value}, function(err,orders) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                status: "error",
                message: err,
            });
        }
else{
        res.json({
            status: "success",
            message: "Orders retrieved successfully",
            data: orders
        });
}
    });
};
```

actually you're sending response in eirther case you were missing else